# What's the difference between the following two ways of testing async functions expected to throw in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Option 1:

```js
await expect(asyncFun()).rejects.toThrowError(errorObj)
```

Option 2:

```js
await expect(async () => {
  await asyncFun()
}).rejects.toThrowError(errorObj)
```

Is there a difference between option 1 and option 2?

Comment: Option 2: Just creates a pointless wrapper, unless you was going to add more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference. The second snippet <s>simply does not work</s> is not documented to work.

Unlike the synchronous [`.toThrow()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror), testing for expected errors asynchronously is not done by passing a function to `expect()`. [`.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects) is meant to be used on a promise, not on a function (although it still seems to call it when it gets one).

Comment: It's my understanding that an `async` function returns a promise, even if only to wrap the returned value or an error. Also even the docs state you can combine `async`/`await` with `.resolves` or `.rejects` (https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait).

Comment: @uzluisf Yes, but they return the promise only when called. `.rejects` is not documented to call functions.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic but what about the example here (https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects), i.e.,  `expect(fetchData()).rejects.toMatch('error');`? The function `fetchData` is being called.

Comment: Yes, the code is calling it and passing a promise to `expect()`. It's not passing a function and having `.rejects` call it.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Jest and NodeJS so some things go over my head at times :'(. This clarifies things, thanks!